# want to sort my log file on this timestamp 2019-06-29T12:39:23.428Z using sort command but confused as there are multiple delimeter

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sorting

This is the format of timestamp on which `2019-06-29T12:39:23.428Z` I want to sort. But the year is delimited by `-` and the time is delimited by `:` and both year and time are separated my `T'`.

```
sort -t '-' -k1 -k2 -k3 -t ':' -k1 -k2 -k3 myLog2.txt
```

Tried this.

Comment: You can't just sort on the entire string?

Comment: Your timestamp has exactly the right structure for`sort myLog2.txt`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can manually pick out each field to sort with -k

from man:

```
     -k, --key=KEYDEF
              sort via a key; KEYDEF gives location and type
```

So something like this should sort your output:

```
sort -k 1,4 -k 6,7 -k 9,10 -k 12,13 -k 15,16 -k 18,19 -k 21,23 <file>
```

However: a simple sort should solve your issue.

```
sort <file>
```

Comment: but the col is based on the delimiter. by default single space is set as delimiter so selecting year-month-dayThour:min:sec.millis is where i am stuck

Comment: You can specify the col by adding the delimiter to -k. like "-k 1.1,1.4" for the first

Comment: I came across some files where the separator for date and time is a. (period) instead of T and separator for time and milis is, (comma) instead of. (period)
for eg:  2019-06-29.12:39:23,428Z ....